# Is there any quick way to dump all of Request.Form values into a smaller faster to type object reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net

It's so clumsy to always be writing Request.Form["blah"]... is there any sort of way I could parse them all out into something smaller like Something.blah?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially wrap this in .NET 4.0 using `dynamic` (note you'd still have to write the code that *provides* the dynamic behaviour, which isn't trivial) - not sure I'd bother though. Note that ASP.NET MVC uses some good code for automatically mapping request inputs (in the route (= path), the form, the query-string, etc) into method parameters and object properties. If you value this kind of automation, try ASP.NET MVC ;-p

Answer (score 2):

No, and it's not clumsy, it's quite appropriate, because you don't know if they will be there, so it can't be done statically.

Comment: There should be something that you can be like new Blah() = Request.Form... Then it will create itself with those params like Blah.formval1, Blah.formval2, etc... right?? like JSON style

Comment: Yes, there is an unlimited number of ways things "should" be. Maybe C# isn't for you ... other, more dynamic languages, may be closer to what you want (but then it really no different, it's just whether or not you write "").

Answer (score 0):

you can use Request["blah"]

that will pull from form, querystring and cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could always use a local variable but still use an indexer:

```
NameValueCollection form = Request.Form;
string x = form["something"];
string y = form["other"];
// etc
```

Personally I wouldn't bother - I don't think it really adds to the readability of the code, but it's your call...

Answer (score 0):

OMG, why didn't anyone mention MODEL BINDING, Marc eluded to MVC.NET but this is exactly what I was looking for.

Finally found a few days later after asking for a way to get an object back from the view page instead of just a request...